# Chronologically store visual selections in a buffer

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

My goal is to enhance the usage of `gv` with counts, in order to access older selections quickly. Such that `2gv` would reselect the selection made before the last.

Vim doesn't have events for entering visual mode, so could it be possible to store them through the `><` marks?

Comment: I dont't quite understand the question: yes, it's possible to store marks / mode and later to re-enter the same selection; no, there's no 100% reliable way to track all transitions (you can map v/V/^V but it's not enough to cover all cases) as there's no such event (and you see it yourself). You'd probably have more success in submitting issue/PR to Vim's github directly (either new event(s) or even new transition stack similar to `:jumps` and `:changes`).

Comment: Yeah there doesn't seem to be any easy way to access the mechanics of `gv` with vimscript. Do you know if there's a way at least to track when marks change? Combined with `mode()` it could be a start.